# BERT masking scheme

Tags: natural-language

From BERT paper, "The masked words were not always replaced by the masked tokens [MASK] because the [MASK] token would never appear during fine-tuning"
What does this mean?
If i just mask 15% words at random and then train my model and use it for fine-tuning, what would happen?

Answer (score 1):

There is a risk that the model would overfit in a strange way. The masked-language-model objective might learn to rely on the `[MASK]` token in the output and it would be impossible to say what would happen if there is something else at the inference time. In this way, they ensure that is familiar with the situation that a real word is at the input.

Comment: Thank you! I think i need to experiment

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, why the chosen token is not always replaced by the special token [mask] is the following:

1. suppose the token x, and its context variable denoted c(x);
2. BERT model tries to learn the function f(x, c(x)) to get a context-sensitive representation of token x;
3. But if the selected token is 100% replaced by the token [mask], then the input x is always [mask], making the input x redundant for learning.